# How to link (AWS) RDS Microsoft SQL Server to front end (react native)

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3

I am doing a project to create a login and create an account page and also store different sorts of data that needs to be securely stored in the database.

I am using react native and amazon web service. I am confused about how to use the RDS(AWS) Microsoft SQL Server and to connect with the front end. Do I use AWS amplify?

I saw a post that mentioned

> Amplify is at the moment tied to dynamoDB in a very strong way. But you can use graphQL queries sent to AppSync (the backend layer of amplify) to trigger lambda functions. From there you can target any type of database you want

Is there a better or shorter process of connecting the front end with the SQL database. Please give me some tips as it is my first time working with AWS and react native.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish this with AWS. You essentially need a backend web server component in your architecture. The classical solution would be to setup an EC2 and have this server handle REST or GraphQL requests that query your RDS.

A more modern "serverless" option would be to route your front-end traffic to an API Gateway that invokes a lambda function. This lambda function can utilize IAM permissions to query your database. There are many resources for this pattern; here's [an AWS blog post about it](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/query-your-aws-database-from-your-serverless-application/).

I'm not familiar with the specifics of Amplify, but if you can be flexible switching datastore it seems convenient just to use a datastore that Amplify plays nicely with. I'd highly recommend trying to get Amplify working if you are not familiar with backend web software and don't have time / care to dig into the complexities of it.